# grep doesn't work in custom shell

Tags: c, shell, grep, execvp

I'm trying to write a shell in c and it mostly works except for grep. Whenever I give a grep command in the shell, it just doesn't output anything. Here is the part of the code I use to create a new child process and then run execvp() in it.

The file descriptors(fd_in and fd_out) in dup2 are passed as arguments to the function which has this code. And most interestingly, when I give 'grep' or 'grep --help' it displays as usual. Am I missing anything? Or something special has to be done with grep?

This is what happens with my shell: The last command outputs when run from bash.

```
--> grep
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try `grep --help' for more information.
--> wc /etc/hosts
 11  33 314 /etc/hosts
--> grep -i "perror" shell.c
-->
```

Here is the code :

```
void 
create_process(char *cmd_argv[], int fd_in, int fd_out, char *buffer_copy) {

    /*Flag bit for Background processes*/
    int FLAG = 0;

    pid_t cpid;
    int status;
    int i = 0,j = 0;

    /*Find the no. of arguments*/
    while(cmd_argv[j] != NULL)
        j++;

    /*Set the flag bit*/
    if(strcmp("&", cmd_argv[j-1]) == 0) {
        FLAG = 1;
        cmd_argv[j-1] = NULL;
    }

    //Create a child process
    cpid = fork();

    if (cpid == -1) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //In the child...
    if (cpid == 0) {

    /*Checking if the file descriptors are already assigned*/

        /*For stdin*/
        if (fd_in != STDIN_FILENO) {
            dup2(fd_in, STDIN_FILENO);
            close(fd_in);
        }

        /*For stdout*/
        if (fd_out != STDOUT_FILENO) {
            dup2(fd_out, STDOUT_FILENO);
            close(fd_out);
        }

        /*Run the cmd specified*/
        status = execvp(cmd_argv[0], cmd_argv);

        /*In case of errors*/
        if(status < 0) {
            perror("execvp ");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    //In the parent...
    else {

        if(FLAG == 1) {
            /*Find where the new bg process can be inserted*/
            while(1) {
                if (bgprocess[i].pid == 0) {
                    bgprocess[i].pid = cpid;
                    strcpy(bgprocess[i].cmd, buffer_copy);
                    break;
                }
                i++;
            }
            printf("[%d] : %s\n", cpid, cmd_argv[0] );
        }

        /*If not bg, wait for the process to exit*/
        else 
            waitpid(cpid, NULL, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us how you setup `cmd_argv`.

Comment: char *cmd_argv[10]; And a previous part of the code fills this with appropriate arguments and then a NULL.

Comment: show a strace of your shell when you run grep. Also, you should probably care about stderr as well as stdin/stdout.

Comment: Does shell.c have an instance of `"perror"` in it? Is your toy shell handling the quotes (**"**) properly or at all? What is the behaviour of grep when it matches nothing? What is grep's return value when it finds nothing? How can your shell read the return value (hint: the second argument of waitpid)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is using the quotes in your shell. Bash does a lot of things in background. 
grep -i perror shell.c should give you output on your shell, whatever is anticipated when run from bash.

Answer (score 0):

Quoth `man dup2`:

> After a successful return from one of these system calls, the old and
>   new file descriptors may be  used  interchangeably. They refer to the
>   same open file description (see open(2))…

Therefore after after your call to dup2 (which you should be checking for error returns) you close `oldfd` and `newfd` because they are the exact same descriptor.

What I can't figure out is why `grep --help` works at all but you aren't showing enough code to answer that question.

**Added following comment**: You still aren't giving enough code. If `grep` isn't working than what is? Does `wc /etc/hosts` work? There is nothing special about grep at all, indeed it is a completely unspecial Unix filter.

Comment: No, that cannot be it. You can _close_ a file descripTOR without affecting the underlying file descripTION -- otherwise you wouldn't be able to redirect just stdout from a process (because stdout and stderr refer to the same open file initially, and you have to close fd 1 before you can dup2 something onto it). Everything _else_ but `close` affects the underlying file description.

Comment: Updated the output of my shell in main post.